# Set a custom images path in Scout

Tags: sass, compass-sass, scout-sass

I'm using the Scout app on Windows 7 to easily work with SASS/Compass. I'm having some incredibly annoying experiences trying to customize the images path that Scout should use.

The Scount configuration UI actually offers a field to set my images path, so I set it to something like this:

**c:\myproject\img**

Next I use a rule in my .SCSS file, for example:

```
@include background(image-url("bg_skin.png"));
```

This compiles into CSS having an image path like this:

**/images/img/bg_skin.png**

Which obviously breaks my image path. I think I am missing the logic here of why I am given the option to set a path, after which it is completely overruled anyway.

As more users seem to have this issue, an update was released:

http://www.continuousthinking.com/2012/05/14/scoutapp-0-6-0-rc1.html

This update allows one to create a custom config file to set paths and such, which will then be used. So I created that file and tell Scout to use it:

```
images_dir = "../img"
```

This compiles into image paths in the CSS like this:

**/../img/bg_skin.png**

Note the leading slash. Again a user-configured path is overruled and again it breaks my path. All I want to do is to tell Scout to use my "img" directory. This drives me insane.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get relative paths you need to add `relative_assets = true` to your `config.rb`. It is all described in that file when you create new project with `compass create`:

```
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true
```